# Which way is better for taking User Input in an OpenGL Android Game?

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch, user-input

I am developing an OpenGL Android Game and I am right now dealing with the User Input.

I have two main ideas for implementing it. The two of them I think that they work perfectly but I do not know which one is "better" (in performance/speed).

The basics are that there are several "buttons" drawn in Opengl (such as four arrow keys, action button...) on some specific positions around the screen. These buttons do not change of place during gameplay.

**FIRST IDEA**

My first implementation was to create a 2D-matrix with references to each button. Something like:

```
InputObject matrix = new InputObject[Width_of_screen][Height_of_screen]
```

At the loading stage each button inserts in the Matrix its references for each pixel where they appear.

So each time the user touches the screen I can look directly on the matrix which button he has clicked (with `e.getX()` and `e.getY()`).

**Pros:** "Fast" to know which button to call.

**Cons:** (At common screens) 800*480 ~ 300K references, with 80% of them being `null` (But memory heap already taken)

**SECOND IDEA**

My second plan is to make an `ArrayList` of the Input Objects and ask each one if its theirs. Something like:

```
for(InputObject ob : TheArrayList){
    if (ob.for_him(e.getX(),e.getY())){
        ob.do_it();
        break; //They cannot overlap
    }
}
```

**Pros:** Less heap space taken (no `null` references at all...)

**Cons:** Have to detect for each object if its for itself, so they need to do comparisons on `for_him` method. Taking more CPU time.

With these said, which one may be the best idea for Android Phones (and other Smartphones) due to having not much processor time for user input.

If there is a third and best approach please I would love to know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know about Picking? I think its the standard way to select in opengl.

Comment: Yes, I know about picking, but in that case AFAIK it would be like getting the X and Y that the Android Touch Event system already provides me.

Comment: no. basically it works like this: your render your scene to an offscreen buffer but with an unique color for each clickable component. Then you can use glReadPixels() together with the x,y for the touch event in order to get the color at the location of the event. Since the color is unique you have the component.

Comment: In that case, with the color got, it would be just like the second idea but with `for_him` simplified, just looking if it is its color. Am I right?

Comment: yeah you got the idea, but you do not have to check if the color belongs to the button. You can put your buttons in a list and encode the index in the list as a color. When you get a color using readPixels() you can decode the color and have the index again.

Comment: but i just realized that this might be a bit too complex for you. If you are sure that you will only have some buttons to click and these buttons do not change position then going with your second idea should be fast enough and much easier to implement.